# How to get total height of 3 p tags inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code

```
<div class="entry-content"> <p>some text...</p> <p>some text...</p> <p>some text...</p> </div>
```

My entry-content div has an absolute positioning, so the text inside the p tags goes under the footer. i have to fix the height of entry-content to total height of all p tags using javascript.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `$('.entry-content').height()`, or similar functions like `.innerHeight()`? ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/)).

You wouldn't need to set the height of the `<div>`, but you could measure the default height, and use that to position your footer.

*A word of warning*: because of text wrapping, the height of that div might change when the window is resized.  You might want to set a callback using `$(window).resize(...)`, to update the positioning when that happens.

Comment: yes `var h1 = $("#primary-page .entry-content p").height();` but it gives only first p tags height

Comment: @Hareesh - what happens if you omit the 'p' from your selector? If those paragraphs are the only thing in that `<div>`, then you could use the height of the div itself, instead of adding up all the paragraphs individually.  (question edited for clarification)

Comment: Added warning about window resizing

Comment: How do i do it? like this `$(window).resize($('#content').height(h1));` ??

Comment: No, `$(window).resize(...)` is for defining a callback function, so you need to give it a function.  For example: `$(window).resize(function () { ... })`, where that function re-calculates the height of your `<div>`, and uses it to update the positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Use [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) (Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, **including padding, border, and optionally margin**.)

```
var total = 0;
$('.entry-content').find('p').each(function() {
  total += $(this).outerHeight(true);
});
$('.entry-content').height(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this... **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B3aRH/1)**

```
var height = 0;
$('div.entry-content p').each(function() {
    height += parseInt($(this).outerHeight(true));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/onepok/1/edit)*

Use: `outerHeight(true)`

```
var entryHeight = $('.entry-content').outerHeight(true);

$('#footer').height(entryHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
var totaltHeight; 
  $('.entry-content p').each(function(){
    totaltHeight = totaltHeight +$(this).height();
  });
});
```

something like that perhaps
this is depended on jQuery

Comment: $('.entry-content p').each(function(){

Answer (score 0):

I made a little jQuery plugin a while back that hopefully will come in handy for a problem such as this:

### Plugin

```
(function ($) {
    // helper 'plugin' for getting the total height
    $.fn.totalHeight = function ()
    {
        var totalHeight = 0;
        this.each(function () {
            totalHeight += $(this).height();
        });

        return totalHeight;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

### Usage

```
var totalHeight = $('.entry-content p').totalHeight();
```

*Edit: This could easily be adapted to support `outerHeight()` or `innerHeight()`.*